# AWK Comparing two files

Tags: awk

I have file 1 as

```
blah    blah    cool
fold    bold    match
ed  ted bled
```

file2 as

```
blah    ha  cool
fold    bold    match
ed  ted bled
```

I want to output rows only if the second field does not match like so

```
blah ha cool
```

Instead however, I'm getting this:

```
blah    ha  cool
fold    bold    match
ed  ted bled
```

Heres my attempt:

```
$ awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next} $1 in a{split(a[$1],r); if (r[2] != 2) print $0 FS "false"; else next;}' file1 file2
```

My guess is that I'm not increment-ing correctly through the associative array..

Comment: You really only need to store `$2` in the array, not the whole line.

Comment: Sorry! i'm working from a much larger example where I do need to store the line since I'm working with other fields.

Comment: Well you want `r[2]!=$2`. I think that's the problem.

Comment: `awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$2]++;next} !a[$2]' file1 file2` should do it.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, you want to print rows from file2 for which the second column differs from the second column in the corresponding row in file1.  If that is the case:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$2; next} $2!=a[FNR]' file1 file2
blah    ha  cool
```

`FNR==NR{a[NR]=$2; next}` saves each value of the second field of file1 in array `a` under the key of its row number.   `$2!=a[FNR]` prints any row from file2 for which the second field differs from the second field of file1 for the same row.

Answer (score 2):

for line by line comparison, assuming tab delimited data

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk '$2!=$5'

blah    blah    cool    blah    ha  cool
```

to only report file2 record

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk '$2!=$5' | cut -f4-

blah    ha  cool
```

This solution will work for very large files as well.